# Whats wrong with my PHP CURL request?

Tags: php, curl

My group uses basecamp for project management and I am the admin. I am trying to figure out how to use the basecamp REST api so that I can create some custom plugins i can use on internal web pages so that team members can write comments directly to basecamp.

I am new to CURL and PHP and so i've started very simple. Just trying to get back the list of projects as a first try. I've hit a brick wall with this.

Here is the API doc: http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/

If I go to https://[mycompanyname].basecamphq.com/projects.xml in a web browser, a popup requests my username and password. Instead of the u/pw I use, i put in my api token and the password "X" like they instruct. It works fine and I get back an XML with all my projects. Great. So I know the api token is fine.

Now trying to do this using PHP and CURL. Heres my code

```
$process = curl_init();
$username = '[my api token]';
$password = 'X';

curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://[mycompanyname].basecamphq.com/projects.xml'); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);                                                                           
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'Content-Type: application/xml', 'Authorization: Basic [my api token]=='));        
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);                                                
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);                                                                         
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);                                                                
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($process);  
curl_close($process);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

Here's the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.0.8
Date: Thu, 01 Mar 2012 11:20:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 401 Unauthorized
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=[removed]
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Runtime: 0.014529
X-Throttle-Count: 1
X-Throttle-Max: 500
X-Throttle-Horizon: 2012-03-01T11:20:20Z

HTTP Basic: Access denied.
```

I can't figure out why. When I inspect the header/response and compare the two, they look nothing alike.

**Header and Response from PHP attempt**

```
Request URL:http://localhost/sandbox/basecamp.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
GET /sandbox/basecamp.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.46 Safari/535.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: MoodleSessionTest=M0QYDbdGlc; MoodleSession=4r2c9g6eset4tg1hhk6h3b8tr2; MOODLEID_=%25EE%25C3%2511H%25BFx%25B1%250A%25EDN%25EF

Response Header
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Mar 2012 11:20:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
Content-Length: 497
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

**Header and Response when I go directly to the URL in chrome**

```
Request URL:https://[my company name].basecamphq.com/projects.xml
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Authorization:Basic [**api code that is different from the one i use**]
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:[removed]
Host:[my company name].basecamphq.com
If-None-Match:"72b1da3a588429c04fe316d1ab0b047d"
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.46 Safari/535.11


Response Headers
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Thu, 01 Mar 2012 10:44:24 GMT
ETag:"72b1da3a588429c04fe316d1ab0b047d"
Server:nginx/1.0.8
Set-Cookie:[removed]
Status:304 Not Modified
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
X-Runtime:0.020332
X-Throttle-Count:1
X-Throttle-Horizon:2012-03-01T10:44:30Z
X-Throttle-Max:500
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

Comment: UGH! After playing with this for 2 hours today, I just got it to work by deleting the "AUthorization: Basic" option from the HTTPHEADER even though the api documentation clearly states: "Authentication is managed using HTTP authentication (only "Basic" is supported right now). Every request must include the Authorization HTTP header." Its amazing how one little annoying oversight on their part can waste 2 hours of my time.

Comment: Note that your first request/response, the one to http://localhost/sandbox/basecamp.php, this is being generated by your web server - you get a 200 OK because your script executed fine. The 401 is being returned by basecamp.